# Controlling for time with cubic splines in mixed model in R

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, splines, intervention-analysis

My aim is to investigate the effect of a change in legislation on behavior in different countries that was measured yearly. All countries of interest adapted the same legislation at different points in time (in different years). I now want to investigate whether changing the legislation had an effect on certain behaviors (e.g. crime rate) in the respective country.

For that, I am trying to set up a segmented mixed effects model with country as random variable that includes:

- random intercepts
- random effects of time (random temporal trends)
- random effects of the intervention
- random effect of interaction between time and intervention (post-intervention temporal trend)

So far I have used the `brms`package:

```
model_brm <- brm(rate ~  (1 + time * legislation | country ) + time*legislation, 
             autocor = cor_ar(~ time | country, p = 1),
             data = data)
summary(model_brm)
```

- *time* is time from intervention < 0 before the intervention, > 0 after the intervention

  *legislation* is an indicator variable, 0 for years before the intervention, 1 for years after the intervention

The main parameter of interest is `legislation`, as it indicates the immediate effect of the intervention.
To single out this effect (and to avoid drawing false conclusions), I want to adjust for time. The model I have built so far assumes a linear relationship between the outcome measure and time, however, the data indicate that a non-linear relationship may be more appropriate.

In a tutorial paper I found the recommendation to flexibly model time through the use of splines and another paper adjusted for time through cubic splines specifically.

My question:

How can I incorporate cubic splines into the mixed effect model to adjust for time? Will I be able to draw useful conclusion from the interaction term using cubic splines?